# How can I create Octagonal mask in CSS

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

I am trying to create a design in which images are octagonal in shape. I used the border hack, but the image needs to be inside the octagon shape. Using pesudo-elements is not apt in this case as the body will also have its own background image. Is it possible with css?

[image]

**My Code**

```css
div {
 width: 100vh;
 height: 100vh;
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

div:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 border-bottom: 29vh solid gold;
 border-left: 29vh solid white;
 border-right: 29vh solid white;
 width: 42vh;
 height: 0;
}

div:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 border-top: 29vh solid gold;
 border-left: 29vh solid white;
 border-right: 29vh solid white;
 width: 42vh;
 height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I wanted this image to be in the golden area : http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg . Also, i used vh so that it is responsive to window height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maLp7hLc/2/)

With background image in fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maLp7hLc/3/)

```
<div class='octa'></div>
```

CSS:

Use image as background like this: `background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature');`

```
.octa {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 250px;
}
.octa:after {
  background-color:#cecece;;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

[image]

```css
.octa {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 100vh;
}
.octa:after {
  background-image: url(http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: auto 100vh;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='octa'></div>
```

Comment: Updated the fiddle and the answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Although your approach is nice, there are a few mistakes : 1) the vendor prefixes, 2) rotation of the pseudo element. I would suggest this code : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/maLp7hLc/5/

Comment: This solution is good, but it uses background image. Is this asked by OP? background-images don't have many control options.

Comment: IMHO, This is the best answer as it uses a single element and it deserves a green tick.

Comment: #ThePragmatick your answer is ok ok. It uses way to many tags and its more easy to understand this answer.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Her answer got more plus votes, so i thought I must accept it. But this one best for me.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I wanted someone to help with icosagon construction. I asked a question but it closed. I think you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: @KillerWhale - I will help you if you please please please remove all the upvotes. :) This will certainly turn out bad _very_ bad for you. Your account will probably get blocked.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py How to remove upvotes? promise to help me afterwards!

Comment: @chipChocolate.py It says - "your vote is locked unless answer is edited". I can't remove them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69300/discussion-between-killer-whale-and-chipchocolate-py).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make a div inside your shape, that contains the picture. And then set the shape's overflow to hidden and background color to transparent, so that only the part of the picture thats inside the shape will show.

And then set the image's height and width to be equal to the div that contains it using this code

```
.pic img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

The final code will look something like this

```
<div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

div {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.pic{
    width:120vh;
    height:120vh;
}
.pic img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 29vh solid transparent;
    border-left: 29vh solid #fff;
    border-right: 29vh solid #fff;
    width: 42vh;
    height: 0;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 29vh solid transparent;
    border-left: 29vh solid #fff;
    border-right: 29vh solid #fff;
    width: 42vh;
    height: 0;
}
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/834ofyxv/)