# Octagon with Border and Background Image

Tags: css, css-shapes

I folowed this answer to create a octagon with a bg image:

[How can I create Octagonal mask in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030659/how-can-i-create-octagonal-mask-in-css)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maLp7hLc/3/)

How do I add a border around it?

```
  .octa {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    @include rotate(45deg);
    width: 100%;
  }
  .octa:after {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: auto 100vh;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    @include rotate(45deg);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not exactly what you need but the approach used here could give you some ideas on how to add the border - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881210/how-can-i-make-octagon-shape-box/29946837#29946837

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very difficult shape to achieve in CSS, i would recommend using SVG as an alternative.

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="50%">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
      <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path d="M25,2
           L75,2
           L98,25
           L98,75
           L75,98
           L25,98
           L2,75
           L2,25z" fill="url(#img1)" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"></path>
</svg>
```

- [SVG MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG)
- [SVG Browser Support (CanIUse)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg)

Comment: That's awesome thanks. But will it support background img? otherwise i found a hexagon version - http://csshexagon.com/

Comment: Ill amend it to use an image for you

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `box-shadow` instead of `border` to create a border effect around the octagon.

What i did:

I gave `box-shadow`s to both the element and the `:after` `pseudo-element` and then added an extra container `div` so that it can hide the `overflow`.

Note: If you want to change the color of the border simply replace the `orange` in the `box-shadow` to a color of your choice and if you want to change the `border-width` replace the `10px` in the `box-shadow` to a width of your choice on both the box-shadows.

```css
.container{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
  transform:rotate(225deg)
}
.octa {
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 250px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 10px orange;
}
.octa:after {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature');
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow:0 0 0 10px orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class='octa'></div>
</div>
```